# MacRuby pointers and Obj-C function returning a value by reference

Tags: objective-c, pointers, reference, macruby, nsrange

I am trying to implement the following method of NSAttributedString in Macruby:

- (id)attribute:(NSString *)attributeName atIndex:(NSUInteger)index effectiveRange:(NSRangePointer)aRange

As by definition, it `Returns the value for an attribute with a given name of the character at a given index, and by reference the range over which the attribute applies.`

OK, so I need a pointer to NSRange, which I set up as follows:

```
range=Pointer.new("{_NSRange=QQ}")[0]
```

It seems to be fine as `range.class` => `NSRange`.

However, when I execute the method:

```
font=txtStor.attribute(NSFontAttributeName,atIndex:index,effectiveRange:range)
```

my `range` is always `#<NSRange location=0 length=0>`. Also, `p range` gives me `#<NSRange location=0 length=0>`.

Any ideas how to implement this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given the solution by Watson at the MacRuby-devel mailing list. I should have written my code like that:

```
 range=Pointer.new(NSRange.type)
 #though range=Pointer.new("{_NSRange=QQ}") would also work
```

then, as I had before

```
font=txtStor.attribute(NSFontAttributeName,atIndex:index,effectiveRange:range)
```

and if needed I could dereference the range by `range[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another valid solution

```
 NSRange range;
 font=txtStor.attribute...effectiveRange:&range);
```

Here the range is passed by reference, in other words the address of the value of range is passed, this allows the value to be changed inside the method and that have that changed remain in the caller.